# PHP Variable Scope

Tags: php, variables, scope, global, constants

Is there a way to declare a variable so it is available in all functions. Basically I want to call: Global $varName; automatically for every function. And no, I can't use a constant.

I don't think its possible but wanted to ask anyway. Thanks! :D

Comment: In all functions? Of A class? Or the entire app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty oldschool and not recommended. If you want to use variables whereever you want consider using sessions of passing through variables if you're on an object oriented tour ;)

Comment: Alright, thats more or less what I thought. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a $GLOBALS variable and a globals keyword.Check out example 1 and 2 on [this page in the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

But using a global variable is usually a sign of bad structure in your code.

Comment: Yah, I was looking at that page earlier. I'll try to come up with a different way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think variables can be globally visible the way you want bnut functions are.

You can declare two functions to access you data : on for reading, one for writing.

But anyway beware : if you change it from many places you will have hard times understanding what's going on when faced with a bug !