# PHP function for loop. not printing the loop

Tags: php

So the loop isn't printing and I don't understand why? I'm only a beginner so I'm really confused on why it won't work. If you guys could explain the reason behind it too that would be great.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$numbers = array(4,6,2,22,11);
sort($numbers);

function printarray($numbers, $x) {
    $countarray = count($numbers);
    for($x = 0; $x < $countarray; $x++) {
        echo $numbers[$x];
        echo "<br>"; 
    }    
}

printarray();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See about variable scope, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. You aren't passing `$numbers` in..

Comment: Another question that could be solved by an introductory tutorial...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781780/php-variable-scope), or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your variable to your function:

```
printarray($numbers);
```

You can also remove the $x from the function as it is being created and destroyed in the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, you might be interested in learning about `foreach`. You can use it to greatly simplify your function like so:

```
<?php
$numbers = array(4,6,2,22,11);
sort($numbers);

function printArray($nums) {
    foreach($nums as $num) {
        echo $num;
        echo "<br>";
    }    
}

printArray($numbers);
```

Experiment via: https://3v4l.org/1BtkK

Once you get used to using `foreach`, take a look at `array_map`, `array_filter`, and `array_reduce` as ways to simplify your code even more.

```
<?php
$numbers = array(4,6,2,22,11);
$sort($numbers);

function printArray($nums) {
    array_reduce($nums, function ($carry, $item) {
        echo $carry .= $item . "<br>";
    });
}

printArray($numbers);
```

Experiment via: https://3v4l.org/4JJFL

And since you are a beginner, check out [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) and practice. Once you have gained experience, check out PHP The Right Way again and practice some more. And again. And again.